# Git merge 2 branches

Tags: git, github

I'm just starting to use GIT, and i'm trying to understand if i'm correct.
Let's say we have branch **Master**, branches **Bug1**, **Bug2**
If i want to merge branch **Bug1** into **Bug2**, i would do something like:

```
git checkout bug2
git merge bug 1
git commit -m "Merged Branch bug1 into branch bug2"
git push
```

So, does it correct way to merge branch **Bug1** into branch **Bug2**?

Comment: Answered on [so]: [Merging 2 branches together in GIT](//stackoverflow.com/q/3404294)

Answer (score 0):

Use patch mode to avoid conflicts. For example:

```
git pull origin master #pull from master

git checkout -p origin/bug1  #patch bug1 branch

git checkout -p origin/bug2  #patch bug2 branch

git checkout -b myMerge #rename branch

git commit -m "Patched diffs from branches bug1 and bug2"

git push
```

**References**

- [The Secret Passions of Git Checkout · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/esmooov/2844353)
- [Git's Patch Mode All the Way](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2016/07/10/git-patch-mode-all-the-way/)
- [Tidier Commits using Git --patch · InVision Engineering Blog](https://engineering.invisionapp.com/post/tidier-commmits-using-git-patch-mode/)
- [Git In The Trenches](https://cbx33.github.io/gitt/afterhours5-1.html)

Comment: Is this equivalent to merging as OP did, then squashing the commits? How is that avoiding merge conflicts?

Comment: @kutschkem This avoids merge conflicts by avoiding merge itself. It is based on the [linux diff](https://loicpefferkorn.net/2014/02/diff-files-what-are-hunks-and-how-to-extract-them/) and [patch](https://kennyballou.com/blog/2015/10/art-manually-edit-hunks/) commands.